# EM algorithm: when M-step is difficult

Tags: expectation-maximization

I'm new to EM algorithm and I'm wondering if there is an easy way for the M-step if the likelihood function is complicated (especially when closed form solution is not easy to find).  It seems that numerical maxmization can be used but I could not find a good reference for it. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Sure, see Section 11.6 ("Optimising the Likelihood by Gradient Methods") in [Barber - Bayesian Reasoning and Machine Learning](http://web4.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/D.Barber/pmwiki/pmwiki.php?n=Brml.Online) (linking to the freely accessible online version on the author's homepage).